# An array of structs w/a closure property that will accept and modify a UILabel

Tags: arrays, swift, uilabel, closures

I'm trying to create a UIPickerView that has rows of descriptive Strings that describe what will happen to a UILabel. Pick a row & that UILabel property change happens to the UILabel. I was hoping to create a struct that has String and closure properties, with the closure accepting and returning a UILabel. I'd then create an array of these structs, populating various array elements with different Strings for the options, and executing the appropriate closure when a row is picked picked.  My guess is I'm not properly thinking through how to set up or call the closures.  I'd been hoping that I can pass in something like this:

label = wheelArray[row].rowFormula(label)

Here's my code up until where I get the error setting up wheelArray:
    import UIKit

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var label: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var pickerControl: UIPickerView!

    struct WheelStruct {
        var rowText: String
        var rowFormula: (UILabel) -> UILabel
    }

var wheelArray = [WheelStruct(rowText: "Font Size = 20", rowFormula: {$0.font.withSize(20)}),
                  WheelStruct(rowText: "Font Size = 30", rowFormula: {$0.font.withSize(30)})]
```

The error I get in the line: var wheelArray... is:
"Cannot convert value of type 'UIFont to closure result type 'UILabel'
I was under the impression that I could pass in a UILabel as $0, and that the changes applied by the methods would simply return the modified UILabel.
I've written code similar to this with more basic closures that could perform simple Double calculations on a struct: (Double) -> Double, with elements initialized like {$0 * 1.6}.
Sincere thanks to anyone who can set my thinking straight on this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> set my thinking straight on this

It's very simple. `{$0.font.withSize(20)}` would return a *font* — a UIFont. But you declared that `rowFormula` is a function that returns a UILabel. That's a mismatch.

> that will accept and modify a UILabel

Here's an obvious approach. Neither returning a font nor returning a label makes any sense here. Instead, make `rowFormula` not return anything — i.e. declare that it returns Void. Now change your actual function so that it *sets* `$0.font` — i.e. it changes the font of the UILabel that is handed to it.

So, for example, just to give you a hint, your anonymous function will start like this: `{$0.font = ...` (Figuring out the rest is left as an exercise for the reader!)

Comment: Very helpful. So I set rowFormula to:  var rowFormula: (UILabel) -> (), and also seem to have messed up the actual structure initialization. This seems to work: {$0.font = $0.font.withSize(20)}. Thanks for solving. I'm really enjoying your book, BTW!

Comment: Thanks! I'd also like to compliment you on your Swifty approach to this, with an array of structs holding functions to match the rows. Very nice idea.